# Audio Fade In/Out with C# in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I just added an audio manager to my android platformer game in Unity and the manager is based on this [video tutorial from Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OT43pvUyfY) and it is working as expected. I would like to ask someone to help me to understand how can I implement an Audio Fade In/Out code (I think it will be a coroutine) so when the game starts all sounds fade in and when I call a function on a button (an Exit game UI button is already created) than all sounds fade out.

I tried to implement a coroutine from my previous UI Manager script but unfortunately somehow I'm having problems to understand the problem. Every other functionalities of the game are working as I wanted.

Music Class.cs

```cs
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Classmusic
{
    public string name;

    public AudioClip clip;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volume;
    [Range(0.1f, 3f)]
    public float pitch;

    public bool loop;

    [HideInInspector]
    public AudioSource source;
}
```

Music Player.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Audio;


public class MPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Classmusic[] music;

    private void Awake()
    {
        foreach (Classmusic m in music)
        {
            m.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            m.source.clip = m.clip;
            m.source.volume = m.volume;
            m.source.pitch = m.pitch;
            m.source.loop = m.loop;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Play("MainMusic");
    }

    public void Play (string name)
    {
        Classmusic m = Array.Find(music, sound => sound.name == name);
        if (m == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Music: " + name + " not found!");
            return;
        }
        m.source.Play();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In my project I use this solution which allows you to select the fading time and the interpolation function for it (e.g Mathf.Lerp, Mathf.SmoothStep etc.).

Sound.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Sound
{
    public string name;
    public AudioClip clip;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volume;
    [Range(.1f, 3f)]
    public float pitch;

    public bool loop;

    [HideInInspector]
    public AudioSource source;

}
```

AudioFade.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class AudioFade
{
    public static IEnumerator FadeOut(Sound sound, float fadingTime, Func<float, float, float, float> Interpolate)
    {
        float startVolume = sound.source.volume;
        float frameCount = fadingTime / Time.deltaTime;
        float framesPassed = 0;

        while (framesPassed <= frameCount)
        {
            var t = framesPassed++ / frameCount;
            sound.source.volume = Interpolate(startVolume, 0, t);
            yield return null;
        }

        sound.source.volume = 0;
        sound.source.Pause();
    }
    public static IEnumerator FadeIn(Sound sound, float fadingTime, Func<float, float, float, float> Interpolate)
    {
        sound.source.Play();
        sound.source.volume = 0;

        float resultVolume = sound.volume;
        float frameCount = fadingTime / Time.deltaTime;
        float framesPassed = 0;

        while (framesPassed <= frameCount)
        {
            var t = framesPassed++ / frameCount;
            sound.source.volume = Interpolate(0, resultVolume, t);
            yield return null;
        }

        sound.source.volume = resultVolume;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
StartCoroutine(AudioFade.FadeIn(mainThemeSound, 3f, Mathf.SmoothStep));
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue here is that you have two volumes, one in Classmusic, and one in the AudioSource source variable which is contained in Classmusic. I'm guessing the play function sets `source.volume = 0;`, but I can't say for sure. Did you try something like this?

```
IEnumerator FadeIn(Classmusic sound) {
    sound.volume = 0;
    sound.source.volume = 0;
    float speed = 0.01f;   

    for (float i = 0; i < 1; i += speed)
    {
        sound.volume = i;
        sound.source.volume = i;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I know it's irritating to set both variables, but it's probably better to keep them in sync. You could also have a SetVolume() function that sets both the AudioSource volume and the variable inside Classmusic class.

Comment: Thanx for the help. I was thinking about a Couroutine as you mentioned earlier. I'm trying to make it work but I'm getting an error message `Failed to call function FadeIn of class MPlayer
Calling function FadeIn with no parameters but the function requires 1.` This is what I don't get. Do I suppose to use `StartCoroutine("FadeIn");` in `void Start()`?

Comment: You've got 2 options for starting coroutines. You can omit the quotation marks and just write it like this: `StartCoroutine(FadeIn(sound));` or add the argument as the 2nd parameter: `StartCoroutine("FadeIn", sound);`. I believe that the 2nd option might only allow 1 parameter, which is fine in this situation.

Comment: John, thank you for your help, this was what I needed. On the other hand, during my reaseach to find an audio manager I found this great Git, and the fade in/out coroutine is embeded in a function with some other goodies. Check it out. Here's the link. [Audio Manager Unity](https://github.com/dinura-imesh/audiomanager-unity).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for my 2d platformer game.
I have a sound fade in/out as my player gets closer/far away from its parent object, I'll call it 'Enemy'.

Audiosource settings on Enemy:

```
Spatial Blend: 1
Volume Rolloff: = Linear Rolloff
Min distance = 1
Max distance = 30
```

Place the audio listener on your player object and it should work.